# How to avoid unnecessary copying of data?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have this function in my code, which takes a few a vectors as arguments, makes a struct from them and push that struct in a queue. Then using a while loop the queue is processed in following manner:

1. If struct satisfying some predefined condition (condition 1) is found then return `true`.
2. If struct satisfying some predefined condition (condition 2) is
   found, discard the struct and continue.
3. Else decompose the current struct into several structs and push each of them in queue.

And at last, return `false` if the whole queue is processed.

Below given code works fine, but I think this code is doing unnecessary copying several times.

```
struct q_element {
    vector<vector<int> > formula;
    vector<int> assignments;
    vector<int> unknowns;
};

bool solve(vector<vector<int> > init_formula, vector<int> init_unknowns, vector<int> init_assignments) {
    q_element t = {init_formula, init_assignments, init_unknowns, };
    deque<q_element> q;
    q.push_back(t);

    while (!q.empty()) {
        t = q.front(); //1. Copy struct from queue to t
        q.pop_front();
        if(satisfiable(t)){
            return true;
        }else if(unsatisfiable(t){
            continue;
        }else{
        vector<int> set=generateSet(t.unknowns);
        for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
            vector<int> term = set[i];
            vector <vector<int> > newFormula=findNewFormula(t.formula, term);
            vector<int> newAssignments=findNewAssignments(t.assignments, term);
            vector<int> newUnknowns=findnewUnknowns(t.unknowns, term);
            q_element temp={ newFormula, newAssignments, newUnknowns }//2. Copy vectors into struct
            q.push_back(temp);//3. Copy struct into queue
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My question is can this unnecessary copying be avoided by using struct of pointers or struct of references or by using queue of struct pointers or any other way?

Comment: Are you using C++11? In some places you could move rather than copy, which is much more efficient.

Comment: @AlanStokes, yes I am using C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a `q_element` by reference:

```
bool solve(const q_element& t) { ... }
```

This "copy":

```
t = q.front(); //1. Copy struct from queue to t
q.pop_front();
```

can be avoided by always referencing `q.front()` instead of `t` and `q.pop_front()` at the end of the while loop.

I'm afraid the second copy is necessary:

```
q_element temp={ newFormula, newAssignments, newUnknowns }//2. Copy vectors into struct
```

and finally, with C++11, the last "copy":

```
q.push_back(temp);//3. Copy struct into queue
```

will just be a "move" operation instead.

Also this:

```
vector<int> term = set[i];
vector <vector<int> > newFormula=findNewFormula(t.formula, term);
vector<int> newAssignments=findNewAssignments(t.assignments, term);
vector<int> newUnknowns=findnewUnknowns(t.unknowns, term);
q_element temp={ newFormula, newAssignments, newUnknowns }//2. Copy vectors into struct
q.push_back(temp);//3. Copy struct into queue
```

can be reduced to:

```
q.emplace_back(
    { findNewFormula(t.formula, set[i])
    , findNewAssignments(t.assignments, set[i])
    , findnewUnknowns(t.unknowns, set[i]) }
);
```

Comment: Along with passing `q_element` by reference, can I also make structure of pointers to further reduce copying?

Comment: @bolov why would it matter in C++11?

Comment: well... creating in place is faster than moving. I agree however that it should’t matter much. It is also more elegant (you don’t need a temp variable).

Comment: actually how you've written it will copy and not move, so it does matter. It can be written to move without emplace back, but as I said, it is more elegant with emplace and why not use it if we have it?

Comment: @bolov added `emplace_back` rewrite.